# CountryPicker UIPickerView calls subclassed method instead of its own

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

So I have this problem with using 2 **UIPickerView** controls in one ViewController. I am using the **CountryPicker** found here https://github.com/nicklockwood/CountryPicker to show a nice country picker so the user can select his or hers country, and the country code for his or hers phone number. I want to limit the number of countries in one of the pickers and show all countries in the other picker. But when I show the 2 pickers, it seems that the one which has **CountryPicker** type is actually using the overriden method **-countriesOfOperation** from the **CustomCountryPicker** class.

I have tried with the storyboard and then to programatically init the 2 pickers without success. As you can see I've tried to remove the first picker before showing the second one and vice versa, but it won't fix it.

What could be the reason that even that I am setting ***countrySelectionPickerView** to be **CountryPicker**, it still uses the overriden method from **CustomCountryPicker**? So the object is of type **CountryPicker**, but it still shows the short countries list.

CustomCountryPicker.h

```
#import <CountryPicker/CountryPicker.h>

@interface CustomCountryPicker : CountryPicker

/// Returns a dictionary of country names, keyed by country code.
+(NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *)countryNamesByCode;

@end
```

CustomCountryPicker.m

```
#import "CustomCountryPicker.h"

@implementation CustomCountryPicker

-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    return [super initWithFrame:frame];
}

+(NSDictionary *)countriesOfOperation
{
    NSDictionary *countries = @{ @"DK": @"Denmark",
                                 @"DE": @"Germany",
                                 @"GB": @"Great Britain",
                                 @"FR": @"France",
                                 @"NO": @"Norway",
                                 @"CH": @"Switzerland"
                                };
    return countries;
}

+(NSDictionary *)countryNamesByCode
{
    NSDictionary *countries = [self countriesOfOperation];
    static NSDictionary *_countryNamesByCode = nil;
    if (!_countryNamesByCode)
    {
        NSMutableDictionary *namesByCode = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
        for (NSString *code in [NSLocale ISOCountryCodes])
        {
            if([countries valueForKey:code]) {
                NSString *countryName = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:code];

                //workaround for simulator bug
                if (!countryName)
                {
                    countryName = [[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleCountryCode value:code];
                }
                countryName = [countryName stringByAppendingString:@" XXX"];
                namesByCode[code] = countryName ?: code;
            }
        }
        _countryNamesByCode = [namesByCode copy];
    }
    return _countryNamesByCode;
}
```

SomeViewController.h

```
#import <CountryPicker/CountryPicker.h>
...
```

SomeViewController.m

```
#import "CustomCountryPicker.h"

@interface SomeViewController () <CountryPickerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *countryPickerView;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *customCountryPickerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CountryPicker *countrySelectionPickerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) CustomCountryPicker *customCountrySelectionPickerView;

-(IBAction)countrySelection:(id)sender {

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] endEditing:YES];
UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;

if(senderButton.tag == 101) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
        self.countryPickerView.hidden = TRUE;
        [self.countrySelectionPickerView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.customCountrySelectionPickerView removeFromSuperview];
        self.customCountrySelectionPickerView = [[CustomCountryPicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 375, 216)];
        self.customCountrySelectionPickerView.tag = 11;
        self.customCountrySelectionPickerView.delegate = self;
        [self.customCountryPickerView addSubview:self.customCountrySelectionPickerView];
        self.customCountryPickerView.hidden = FALSE;
        self.customCountryPickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 260, SCREEN_WIDTH, 260);
    } completion:nil];

    // update user country

// select user country phone code
} else if(senderButton.tag == 102) {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 delay:0.0 options:0 animations:^{
        self.customCountryPickerView.hidden = TRUE;
        [self.countrySelectionPickerView removeFromSuperview];
        [self.customCountrySelectionPickerView removeFromSuperview];
        self.countrySelectionPickerView = [[CountryPicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 375, 216)];
        self.countrySelectionPickerView.tag = 12;
        self.countrySelectionPickerView.delegate = self;
        [self.countryPickerView addSubview:self.countrySelectionPickerView];
        self.countryPickerView.hidden = FALSE;
        self.countryPickerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, SCREEN_HEIGHT - 260, SCREEN_WIDTH, 260);
    } completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the library is using `static` variables so both your custom subclass and the original `CountryPicker` share the data. You can remove the `static` keyword from `_countryNames`, `_countryCodes`, `_countryNamesByCode` and `_countryCodesByName` and it should work.